# Median of geometric distances : searching for a weight function.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, geometry, optimization, numerical-methods

Inspired by a question that sadly was deleted so it would not make much help linking to it, but anyway. The question was about how to calculate the $2D$ geometric median either with respect to all vectors $\bf v \in \mathbb R^2$ or the set we are measuring distances to ${\bf x_k}\in\mathcal S$.

---

Let $$\mu = \frac 1 N \sum_{k=0}^N {\bf x_k}$$

Now to my question, can we

1. **Prove or disprove** there exists a function ${\bf x_k} \to w(|\mu - {\bf x_k}|)$ so that a linear optimization $${\bf v_o} = \min_{\bf v}\left\{\sum_k w({\bf x_k})\left\|{\bf x_k-v}\right\|_2^2\right\}$$ so that $\bf v_o$ is the median.
2. Derive such a function
3. If the result of 1. is that no such function exist, to show that if the procedure is iterated, there exist such functions which will converge to a solution.

Comment: You're aware of [Weiszfeld's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median#Computation)? Although its weight function $w$ uses the previous estimate of $\bf v_o$ instead of $\mu$.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, I think it was mentioned in the deleted question. That is probably what inspired this question.